# Inner Join ORM Django

Tags: python, django

Tenho 2 models:

```
class MdlCourse(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(MdlCourseCategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sortorder = models.BigIntegerField()
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=254)

class MdlCourseCategories(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Quando eu rodo dá o seguinte erro:

> (1054, "Unknown column 'mdl_course.category_id' in 'field list'")

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Você rodou o comando migrate para sincronizar o banco de dados ? PS: Não é necessário criar o campo id, ele é criado automagicamente... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erro corrigido.
Como comentado acima, o Django define automaticamente o nome da coluna de Chave Estrangeira. Acontece que o banco de dados já existe e eu estou fazendo um sistema partindo dele.

Portanto, não posso seguir a convenção do Django. Para isso tive que pesquisar muito e descobrir que existe um parâmetro que se passa na coluna da Classe do Model para que ele utilizasse o nome real da coluna.

Abaixo:

```
class MdlCourse(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(MdlCourseCategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column = 'category')
    sortorder = models.BigIntegerField()
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=254)

class MdlCourseCategories(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

O nome do parâmetro é `db_column`. E o valor que se dá a ele é o nome real da coluna.